# Hadoop ls vs unix ls

Tags: hadoop

This may be a silly question but I am very new to Hadoop.
I have a unix server path as `/tmp/abc` where I am writing a file test.txt from Informatica BDM using hadoop connection. A part of Hadoop cluster resides in this unix server.
Now my question in when I do
`ls /tmp/abc` and 
`hadoop fs -ls /tmp/abc`
The second command shows the file but not the first one.
Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

`hadoop fs`, of course, is the Hadoop filesystem that is configured in your Hadoop client. This is typically HDFS, but it could also be local `file`, AWS `s3`, Azure `wasb`, among others. All are basically abstractions of a file system over many machines.

Anything not using the `hadoop` command is just a local disk mount.

You could make the two commands the same by comparing `hadoop fs -ls file:///tmp/abc`

Answer (score 0):

Not really Informatica related question ;) Anyway as far as I know HDFS is... well, a File System. So you will not be able to see the files via shell commands checking your 'external' file system, whether it's Unix or Windows.

That is why you need to use `hadoop fs -ls` - this way you ask Hadoop to run the `ls` command on your Hadoop File System.

Here's a buch of stuff that might be useful:

http://www.bmcsoftware.pl/guides/hadoop-hdfs.html

https://hortonworks.com/blog/windows-explorer-experience-hdfs/